# linq to sql: creation of class from query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-4.0

I'm trying to use LINQ to SQL in my project and I have a question:

Actually here is my test code:

```
DataContext dc;
var result = dc.ExecuteQuery<myClass>(string.Format(@"
    SELECT
        FieldA, FieldB, FieldC, FieldD
    FROM
        mySqlTable
    WHERE 
    FieldA > 10
    ORDER BY FieldA
"));
```

and my `myClass` declaration:

```
public class myClass
{
    public int FieldA { get; set; }
    public string FieldB { get; set; }
    public int FieldC { get; set; }
    public int FieldD { get; set; }

    public myClass()
    {
    }
}
```

**The question**: is there an automatic mode to create for the first time the class declaration? *(now I made it by hand)*

Comment: If you use `ExecuteQuery` with a SQL string, you're not really using Linq2Sql.  You can use [Dapper to generate a POCO](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) (plain old C# object)  It's what StackOverflow uses itself.

Comment: @andomar well, dapper can *populate* POCOs; it doesn't create the C#. You can, however, use `dynamic` - then you don't even need a POCO - great for queries where the data is used locally, for example inside the same method rather than returning an object up a few layers

Comment: @MarcGravell: I must remember Dapper as even more awesome than it is :)  Can Dapper return a property bag?  Say a list of dictionaries, `[{'id': 1, 'name': 'bert'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'ernie'}, ...]`.  With a property bag the OP would not have to declare a C# class.

Comment: @Andomar yup; `DapperRow` is used for `dynamic`, but allows indexer-based access too, and implements `IDictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic mode for the creation of classes can be adapted by the following way in edmx.Here two models are generated xxxx.Context.tt and xxxx.tt. So,every time you make a change in db and update in edmx automatically they both xxxx.Context.tt and xxxx.tt are updated.

you can  have a look over here how to create it.
 After creating your dbmx or edmx,

From the same project right click
 1. select  Add NewItem
  On the top Left hand side
 2. Select Code
 3. Select EF 4.x DbContextGenerator.

[image]
For more info regarding this you can follow this url
[more on autogeneration of models](http://csharppulse.blogspot.in/2013/08/learning-mvc-part-3-creating-mvc.html)